# Terraform Azure Function Get ClientId Secret

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to automate the app registration of an azure function via terraform but not sure how to do this. Here is my terraform (see below), I am trying to create the app registration at the same time so that I can get the `client_id` and `client_secret` which will get stored in key vault so I can use it later on. According to the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/windows_function_app#identity I can pass an `active_directory` block?

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "func" {
  name                        = local.function_name
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  storage_account_name        = azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.name
  storage_account_access_key  = azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id             = module.appserviceplan.appserviceplan_id
  functions_extension_version = "~4"
  tags                        = var.tags

  site_config {
  }

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION       = "~4"
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME          = "dotnet"
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE          = "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azuread_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application) and [azuread_application_password](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_password) to generate a `client_id` and `client_secret`.